# How does casting between Cs default int type and <stdint.h>'s intXX_t types work?

Tags: c, stdint

I'm working in a code skeleton that has a lot of preexisting code using the regular old `int` type in C. However, the code I need to write requires that I use a fixed length `int32_t`. However, I need to be able to take input from the regular code in terms of `int`, and output to variables that are also just regular `int`. Does casting from `int32_t` to `int` preserve the value of the variable, or the specific data representation of it (in which case I may need to bitshift in order to preserve the value). Conversely, does casting from `int` to `int32_t` introduce any complications? Any answer would be greatly appreciated, but especially any that generally and specifically explain the casting conventions of the `stdint` library.

Comment: The value will be preserved if it's within the range of both types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does casting between Cs default `int` type and <stdint.h>'s `intXX_t` types work?

When `intXX_t` and `int` same size, range and effective type, no "work" really happens.

When `intXX_t` has wider range than `int`, all values are preserved in the new type.  The upper bits are a sign extension.

When `intXX_t` has narrower range than `int`, out of range values are converted in an *implementation defined* way.  This is *very commonly* a mod like wrap around (lower bits are the same)

When `intXX_t` has same range as `int`, the types *may* differ, but usually are the same.  In select code (as with `_Generic`), the difference is important.

---

`int` comes in various sizes and encoding.

- 32-bit (2's complement): This is quite common, especially on desktop computers.
- 16-bit (2's complement): This is common in small embedded processors.
- Other: including Non-2's complement, 64-bit on some 64-bit graphics processors, some non-power-of-2 on old or esoteric machines.  For OP's concerns, simply know others exists, but it is *very* unlikely OP needs to port code to or from such machines.

---

> Does casting from `int32_t` to `int` preserve the value of the variable, or the specific data representation of it (in which case I may need to bitshift in order to preserve the value).

Bit shifting not needed.

- 32-bit (2's complement):  Casting `int32_t` to `int` does not lose any value information.  In select situations, a *type* change may happen.  `int32_t` may have been type def'd as a `long`, yet far more likely `int32_t, int` are exactly the same type.
- 16-bit (2's complement):  Casting `int32_t` to `int` loses info as the the range is much smaller.  On such machines, better to cast `int32_t` to `long`.

---

> Conversely, does casting from `int` to `int32_t` introduce any complications?

- 32-bit (2's complement): Very unlikely any problem.
- 16-bit (2's complement):  Some situations deserve review as `int32_t` is wider and takes up more space.

---

Well written code is less likely to cause issues, yet much code does not consider portability.

For OP's case, I recommend to create macros, rather than direct casting.  This will facilitate tracking the change to your code base due to the new work requirement.  Further, alternatives could then readily be used to debug range reduction/increase issues.

```
// Use names per your coding style
#define inttoint32(i) ((int32_t) (i))
#define int32toint(i32) ((int) (i32))
```